# Access Oracle View to Generate reports in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, reports, oracle

I have one view created in oracle database and I need to display some reports based on it on a SharePoint 2013 enterprise farm.

I want to know which approach is preferable, should I create a BCS eternal list to generate the reports on or should I generate SSRS directly using credentials?

Can anyone suggest me the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of absolutely no reason to use an external list for SSRS when a direct Oracle connection is available. I also think your performance would be much better, depending on the size of the view. There's no downside to the direct connection, save BCS external lists for use as a column type.

Comment: Any refrerence URL you can suggest to do this?

Comment: Try this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220591(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: In that article I note that (under Remarks) the .NET Oracle provider must be loaded on the dev machine and the server